# To what extent can a noun be used as an adverb?

Tags: parsing

> 彼女の細い指先を、舌がぬらりと踊ると、明かりに反射した光がうっすらと手に貼りついた。
>
> Once her tongue slid around in a dance, she gently stuck the the "明かりに反射した光" (spit?) onto her hand using her slim fingers.

(normally there isn't anything that hard to read in a H-scene, but if you havn't realized the context is a BJ, with the speaker asking her to used her hands along with her mouth with spit as lubricant :X)

- can 明かりに be an adverb, as if  明かり is a na-adj? Is 明かりに反射した光 gibberish regardless?
- Is the meaning between 指先を光が手に貼りついた and 指先が光を手に貼りついた interchangeable?

Comment: "the light(光) that is reflected from the light(明かり/電灯/照明)." って言いたいんでしょうけど、「明かりに反射した光」ではおかしいと思います。。。（「照明**に**光が反射する」わけじゃないので。）「反射した明かり/照明の光が手に貼りついた」とか「明かり/照明(から)の光が反射して、手に貼りついた」とかになるんじゃないですかね・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

明かりに is not an adverb.  明かりに反射した光 means the light that is reflected from the (surrounding) illumination.

it's not 指先を光が手に貼りついた, it's 彼女の細い指先を舌がぬらりと踊る or her tongue danced on her fingers.

Comment: would you say 明かりに反射した光 would qualify under [defition 4: 動作・作用・変化の結果を表す。「危篤に陥る」「水泡に帰する」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/) (Indicates the results of a change/action/) ?

Comment: That 明かり is origin/source of the light. 明かりに反射した光 is a paraphrase for 明かりに照らされた光. So, that に stands for cause as in examples like 雨に濡れる explained in ⑦原因  http://coffeejp.com/article/yufa/2007-03-12/article_528.html

Comment: Is を in 指先を舌がぬらりと踊る indicating Area instead of direct object as well?

Comment: Yes, it indicates surface on which the object moves.

Answer (score 0):

明かりに is not an adverb.

反射する means "to be reflected"

Example
声が山に反射する。
The voice is reflected by the mountain.
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/181252/meaning/m0u/反射/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/181252/meaning/m0u/%E5%8F%8D%E5%B0%84/)

So the translation becomes:
明かりに反射した光
The light that was reflected by the lamp.